# How to mount a LVM partition within a LVM volume?

Tags: lvm

I have built a VG named cinder-volumes. Within this VG, I created a PV named leader-volume. Then I mounted this PV as the root filesystem of a KVM Ubuntu installation. During the installation process, I selected LVM partition.
At last, I created a snapshot for the PV leader-volume.
Now I want to read some files within my Ubuntu installation... What shall I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `kpartx` - it's especially useful for managing VMs where entire file systems are often packed into single volumes. 
`kpartx` can create device nodes for partitions nested on a block device or disk image.

Mount (one of the following):

```
kpartx -av your_vm_disk.img
```

```
kpartx -av /dev/mapper/your_device
```

Where `your_device` could be an LVM partition. The `-v` option causes `kpartx` to display the devices it creates for nested partitions.

Mount the appropriate /dev/mapper/loopXpX:

```
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt
```

Unmount (after unmounting loop devices):

```
umount -d /dev/mapper/loop0
```

```
umount -d diskimage.img
```

Remove the device mappings:

```
kpartx -dv your_vm_disk.img
```

```
kpartx -dv /dev/mapper/your_device
```